# Hide table border when printing in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to set css style sheet to remove border from whenever I print document for my client, however the table border is still display.

Here is my html script to do so:

```css
@media print {
  .table-bordered>thead>tr>th,
  .table-bordered>tbody>tr>th,
  .table-bordered>tfoot>tr>th,
  .table-bordered>thead>tr>td,
  .table-bordered>tbody>tr>td,
  .table-bordered>tfoot>tr>td {
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered">

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:25%;">
        លេខគណនី/ Account Number
      </td>
      <td style="width: 50%"> 0001</td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="" class="px">
                            <span class="lbl">ផ្ទេរចូល/ Transfer</span>
                        </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        ឈ្មេាះគណនី / Account Name
      </td>
      <td> Jonh David</td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="" class="px">
                            <span class="lbl"> សាច់ប្រាក់ / Cash</span>
                        </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        ចំនួនទឹកប្រាក់ជាលេខ / Amount in figure
      </td>
      <td>100,000.00 $ </td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="" class="px">
                            <span class="lbl"> មូលប្បទានបត្រ / Cheque/ Cash</span>
                        </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        ចំនួនទឹកប្រាក់ជាអក្សរ / Amount in word
      </td>
      <td>100,000.00 $</td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="" class="px">
                            <span class="lbl"> មូផ្សេងៗ / Other </span>
                        </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <div class="topAlign">
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="height:100px;">
          <p style="position:relative;top:-26px;"></p>
        </td>
      </div>
      <td valign="top">
        <p style="position:relative;top:-26px;">ប្រភេទសាច់ប្រាក់ / Denomination</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have no clue why this does not work for `border` property but when I tried another CSS property something like `display:none;` or `margin-left: 20px;` it is just working fine.

I don't know what wrong with that,how can I do to archive this?

Please kindly help, thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `!important` ? Your style won't work without it because bootstrap uses `!important` to set the tables borders when printing. You can see it on the [source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/0b9c4a4007c44201dce9a6cc1a38407005c26c86/less/print.less#L93).

Comment: @AndréAdriano, yes I have tired `!important` already to override bootstrap table class, but it still does not work. Thanks

Comment: @HouyNarun did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm having the same issue